# cant re run select query unless i close and open the form again

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, select, windows-forms-designer

hi i'm using this function in a c# windows form application to get a row from my database and bind the results to textboxes 
it works fine and fast but if i run it again (get another row) it crashes
i can run the query again only if i close the form and reopen it

i can run an insert query multiple times and it works perfect

do i have to dispose anything else ?? 
what am i doing wrong

**UPDATE:** i put it in try catch and i got this exception message :
This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same property,Parameter name: binding

```
    private void loadcar()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn = dbclass.getconnection();
        conn.Open();
        // Create the command
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE CarId LIKE '"+ caridtxt.Text.ToString()+"'", conn);
      //  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carid", caridtxt.Text.ToString());
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds, "Car");
        command.Dispose();
        adapter.Dispose();
        if (ds.Tables["Car"].Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            if ((int)ds.Tables["Car"].Rows[0]["CarDest"] == 0)
            {
                cardest0radio.Checked = true;
            }
            else { cardest1radio.Checked = true; }
            if ((int)ds.Tables["Car"].Rows[0]["HaveKeys"] == 0)
            {
                carhavenkradio.Checked = true;
            }
            else { carhavekradio.Checked = true; }

            if ((int)ds.Tables["Car"].Rows[0]["CarIsFree"] == 1)
            {
                carfreechk.Checked = true;
                carmsnametxt.ReadOnly = false;
                carfdate.Enabled = true;
                carmsnametxt.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables["Car"], "FreeName");
                carfdate.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables["Car"], "FreeDate");
            }
            else
            {
                carfreechk.Checked = false;
                carmsnametxt.ReadOnly = true;
                carfdate.Enabled = false;
            }

            carbrandcmb.SelectedValue = ds.Tables["Car"].Rows[0]["CarBrand"].ToString();
            carmodelcmb.SelectedValue = ds.Tables["car"].Rows[0]["CarModel"].ToString();
            carengtxt.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables["Car"], "CarEngine");
            carmilagetxt.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables["Car"], "Milage");
            carprctxt.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables["Car"], "BookPrice");
            caryeartxt.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables["Car"], "CarYear");
            carbfromtxt.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables["Car"], "BoughtFrom");
            carbpricetxt.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables["Car"], "BuyPrice");
            carbinvtxt.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables["Car"], "BInvNum");
            carinscotxt.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables["Car"], "InsComp");
            carshnametxt.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables["car"], "Shmai");
            carbmemotxt.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables["Car"], "Memos");
            carbdate.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables["Car"], "DateOfBuy");
            if ((int)ds.Tables["Car"].Rows[0]["CarIsSold"] == 1)
            {
                carhavenkradio.Checked = true;
            }
            else { carhavekradio.Checked = true; }
        }
        else { MessageBox.Show("Car Not Found"); }
        ds.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: what's the excetpion if any coming?

Comment: put it in try-catch block, and paste exception message here...

Comment: Maby you should not set the Binding multiple times.
try to set the binding one time and if you re-call the function, then check if a binding exists. If no then you can rebind it, if yes, then do nothing.